# My app runs succesfuly in android studio emulator but it only shows something went wrong and no error is shown in logcat

Tags: android, kotlin, emulation

I don't know what's the problem, I am new to android studio I follow the tutorial create the app, there is no error in code, and when I run the app it runs succescfuly and the screen only shows something went wrong, and there is nothing to display in logcat not any error message!!

Though when I test the app on my android device the logcat works and it shows me the errors, and this is what I get if anyone can help me

```
2022-03-25 19:26:08.569 16438-16438/? E/nApps.myweathe: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2022-03-25 19:26:09.303 16438-16438/com.TonnApps.myweather E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
2022-03-25 19:26:09.729 16438-16438/com.TonnApps.myweather E/GraphicExt: Can't load libboost_ext_fwk
2022-03-25 19:26:09.729 16438-16438/com.TonnApps.myweather E/GraphicExt: GraphicExtModuleLoader::CreateGraphicExtInstance false
2022-03-25 19:26:09.769 16438-16524/com.TonnApps.myweather E/gralloc: Arm Module v1.0
2022-03-25 19:26:09.770 16438-16524/com.TonnApps.myweather E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
```

Comment: You might have a filter turned on in LogCat that’s filtering out your app messages.

Comment: The thing is that when I test the app on my emulator it shows me nothing in logcat but if I test the app on my android device I still get the same error the app launches on the main screen it just writes "Something went wrong" and that's it, but on my android device I do get messages in logcat, in my emulator I dont see anything so I guess i'll just test every app on my android device than ! maybe it is better ?